# error of bind parameter in php mysqli statement

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$Statement= mysqli_prepare( $this->mysqli,'UPDATE empData SET Name=?, 
                            Email=?,
                            PhoneNumber = ?, 
                            AddressLine1 =?,          
                            AddressLine2 =?, 
                            CityID =?, 
                            Zip = ?, 
                            ModifiedOn = now()
                            WHERE id = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($Statement, 'sssssisi', trim($name), 
                        trim($email), 
                        trim(phnumber), 
                        trim(address1), 
                        trim(address2), 
                        $city=2, 
                        trim($zipcode), 
                        $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($Statement);
```

The query gives me an error on server strict standards: value pass by reference on line where i used trim and `$city=2`

Locally it runs fine, but on the server it gives me the above error?

Is any another way to write these query using mysqli?

Comment: Try with giving this value in the brackets.

Comment: why writing $city=2 instead of '2' directly, and trim those values at the time you are gettin those values in variables

Comment: `is any another way to write these query using mysqli procedural style?` what you have written is using the procedural style my friend

Comment: What type of brackets should i used Broken Heart? can you give me example?

Comment: Deepanshu when i directly used 2 it gives me error in bind_param